# Bilateral Laplace transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

My knowledge of Bilateral Laplace transform is less. Here are the few questions I need answer.

1. What is the condition for existence of bilateral Laplace transform?
2. How is the condition for existence related to ROC ?
3. What's the bilateral Laplace transform of $\sin \omega t$ ?
4. How is the bilateral Laplace related to Fourier transform and the condition to transform one to another.

Answer (score 1):

1. A *sufficient condition* that $f(t)$ has bilateral Laplacian transform $\mathcal{B}\{f(t)\}(s)$ if $e^{-st}f(t)$ absolute integrable, i.e. 
   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |e^{-s t}f(t)|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-Re(s)t}|f(t)|<\infty$$
2. Range of convergence of bilateral Laplacian transform is defined 
   $$ \mathrm{ROC}=\left\{s\Bigg| \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-Re(s)t}|f(t)|<\infty\right\}$$
3. $$\mathcal{B}\{\sin a t\}(i s) = \pi i \left( \delta (a-i s)- \delta
       (a+i s)\right)$$ where $\delta(x)$ is a Dirac Delta Function

   In detail:

   I have found in some table that  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty
   e^{-ixy}f(ax)\sin bx dx = \frac{1}{2ai}\left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty
   e^{-ix{\frac{y-b}a}}f(x) dx- \int_{-\infty}^\infty
   e^{-ix{\frac{y+b}a}}f(x) dx \right)$$

   In your case $f(x)=1$, $a=1$, $b=\omega$, so $$ \mathcal{B}\{\sin
   at\}({is})= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-its}\sin at dt =
   \frac{1}{2i}\left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it{{(s-a)}}} dt-
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it{{(s+a)}}} dt \right)$$ which is the
   the answer above is obtained since
   $$\delta(x-a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it{{(x-a)}}}
   dx,$$ see  [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform1.html)  ,[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47732/bilateral-laplace-transform).
4. The continuous Fourier transform is equivalent to evaluating the bilateral Laplace transform with imaginary argument $s = iω$ or $s = 2πfi$:$$
     \hat{f}(\omega) = \mathcal{F}\{f(t)\} 
                 = \mathcal{B}\{f(t)\}|_{s = i\omega}  =  F(s)|_{s = i \omega} 
                 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i \omega t} f(t)\,dt. \\
   $$

---

You might be interesting in a "Advanced Mathematical Analysis" book by Richard Beals.

Comment: When I'm checking absolute integrability of $sin \omega t$ , it's giving me $\infty$. So, how's the bilateral Laplace of it possible?

Comment: $e^{Re(s)t}\sin(\omega t)$ should be absolute integrable, not $\sin(\omega t)$

Comment: I don't know where I'm making mistake. I'm still getting infinity. I'm trying to solve $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |e^{-\sigma t}sin t| dt$ by splitting $sin$ in exponential form and then applying the limit. Could you please show me how did you solve the integration and found the bilateral laplace of $sin$

Comment: There is a link with a program which I used to obtain it. This is a script for Mathematica.

Comment: But why am I getting $\infty$ when I'm checking the condition of existence.

Comment: see the $ $edit

Comment: If $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |e^{-\sigma t}sin(\omega t)|dt$ won't converge for any value, so there should not be any bilateral transform for it.

Comment: Not really, the values of $s$ it converges for given $\omega$ define ROC for that case.

Comment: Could you explain it a little more ?

Comment: 1) different $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$ is different function. 2) This function converges for $s=ix$, i.e. ROC $=0$. 3) I've edited the answer to make it clear and to add some details to clarify things. 4) To the question why $\sin \omega t$ has Bilateral Laplace Transform when $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |e^{-\sigma t}sin(\omega t)|dt$ diverges. The answer is simple, This condition isn't necessary, just sufficient.

Comment: Is there any necessary condition for existence ? How did you find ROC, the formula you've given is not very much clear. The book you've referred is too expensive here in India.

Comment: I don't know if there is a necessary condition. Try to find in the library the book I've stated in the answer (I don't have it). If there is such a condition you should be able to find it there. I'm afraid there is no such condition though. If you find it -please post it here.

Comment: How did you find ROC, the formula you've given is not very much clear.

Comment: the ROC I stated in the comment is wrong. According to the definition in my answer it would be empty set. However, I believe it is necessary to define an extension to the definition in order to distinct between absolute and conditional convergence and rate of convergence. What we have here is a conditional convergence for $\{i s|s\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: How did you know that it's conditional convergent ?

Comment: I've found necessary and sufficient conditions [here](https://archive.org/stream/laplacetransform031816mbp). But I'm not getting it. Actually I'm not getting anything written in it.

Comment: where did you find the necessary condition? Looks like I missing it.

Comment: on page 272 in the book in the link

Comment: The theorem 21 is not what you looking for, in their terms you asking condition for $d\alpha(t)$ but the theorem states condition for function $f$ to have the following representation $f(x)=\int e^{-xt} d\alpha(t)$.

Comment: In the index it was written "necessary and sufficient conditions for representation as a bilateral Laplace transform" on page 404.

Comment: yes, this is representation of $f(t)$ as Bilateral Laplace Transform, but you want condition for $d\alpha$ to have the transform.